# openCV doesn't compile on Leopard

Tags: macos, opencv, compilation, osx-leopard

I've been for the past few hours trying to figure out why `openCV` doesn't compile on leopard. I've been googling for references but all point to a dead google group.

So my question is quite simple: I've read INSTALL file, read all documentation *i* could find and still couldn't figure a solution for this.

The compile breaks here (this is generated through the Makefile):

> `rm -fr`
>   `.libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a mkdir`
>   `.libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a`
>   `Extracting /Users/fmsf/Projects/Motion`
>   `Tracking/Libs/opencv-1.1.0/cxcore/src/./.libs/lib_cxcore.a (cd .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a`
>   `&& ar x /Users/fmsf/Projects/Motion`
>   `Tracking/Libs/opencv-1.1.0/cxcore/src/./.libs/lib_cxcore.a) ar: /Users/fmsf/Projects/Motion: No`
>   `such file or directory make[2]: ***`
>   `[libcxcore.la] Error 1 make[1]: ***`
>   `[check-recursive] Error 1 make: ***`
>   `[check-recursive] Error 1`

Does anyone know what *i* could do to build it?
I'm using mac os 1.5 leopard, while reading *i* found the full port for Mac OS is still unfinished, but I don't really believe it's the missing of this library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error, my suggestion is:

Try building it in a folder that doesn't have spaces in the name.

("/Users/fmsf/Projects/Motion Tracking/" vs "ar: /Users/fmsf/Projects/Motion: No such file or directory")

Answer (score 0):

you may be trying 1.1. this is pretty new. consider trying 1.0. i have built 1.0 on windows and ubuntu.

Comment: Yes indeed is 1.1 i'll go and try the 1.0 and reply here shortly after ty